# Can I use Microsoft Kinect SDK v2.0 to get Skeletal Tracking information from TWO Kinects connected to the same PC?

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

How can I connect and use multiple Kinect sensors (v2.0) with MS Kinect SDK on the same PC?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The official Microsoft SDK only supports one Kinect an the same PC.
The [open source driver (libfreenect2)](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2) supports multiple Kinects on the same PC, but doesn't have skeletal tracking.

But you can run each Kinect on its own PC and stream the data to one central processing PC. There are multiple projects going that direction:

- [KV2Streamer](https://github.com/Samsung/kv2streamer) allows you to stream all Kinect data (including skeletal tracking) from one PC to another.
- [LiveScan3D](https://github.com/MarekKowalski/LiveScan3D/) builds point clouds out of the data of multiple Kinects connect over LAN. They don't include the skeletal tracking data yet, but they said they are working on including it. They also take care of the calibration for you, so all Kinects work in the same coordinate system.
- There is also Micorsoft's [RoomAliveToolkit](https://github.com/Kinect/RoomAliveToolkit) that builds an augmented reality using multiple Kinects and multiple projectors.